# Как получить ссылку вида /action/slug, а не action?slug=slug через URL::to(0 в Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Здравствуйте. Имеется правило URL:

```
'/album/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>' => '/site/album'
```

Но при попытке генерации URL через `Url::to()` получаю ссылку вида:

> /album/slug=some-slug

Вместо желаемой:

> /album/some-slug

Пробовал так, но не выходит:

```
Url::to(['/site/album', 'slug' => 'some-slug']);
Url::to(['/site/album', 'slug' => 'some-slug'], true);
```

Полная конфигурация URL-менеджера:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '' => 'site/index',
                '<action>' => 'site/<action>',
                '<controller>' => '<controller>/index',
                '/album/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>' => '/site/album',
            ],
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите такое правило в url rules -

```
'album/<slug:.+>' => 'site/album/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема вызвана порядком правил. Необходимо изменить их порядок:

```
'rules' => [
    '' => 'site/index',
    '/album/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>' => '/site/album',
    '<action>' => 'site/<action>',
    '<controller>' => '<controller>/index',
],
```

*via qonand*

Answer (score 0):

```
 попробуй прописать так 
 '<action:(album|login|signup)>' => 'site/<action>',
```